# Runtime error whle exporing range to pdf

Tags: vba, excel

I get a run time error when I am trying to export a 'sheet' / 'range in a sheet' as pdf no matter where i keep the code in sheet or a different module, no matter what path i give. I have tried numerous codes. Lising a few below. I always get an error. Any idea why?

**Error**
Run-time error '5';
Invalid procedure call or argument

Codes that I tried:

```
Sub try()
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:F10").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, fileName:= _
    "c:\Book1.pdf", Quality:= _
    xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False
End Sub
```

.

```
Sub luxation()
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:F10").Select
    Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        fileName:="temp.pdf", _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=True
End Sub
```

.

```
Sub Sample()
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Activate

    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    fileName:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Survey Report.pdf", _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: What version of excel are you using?

Comment: Microsoft Office Excel 2007 (12.0.4518.1014)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The procedure below will export to the specified location a PDF:

```
'rng - The range you wish to be exported'
'strFP - The file path to save the PDF to'

Public Sub fExportPDF(rng As Range, strFP As String)

'Export as PDF
With rng
    .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=strFP, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
End With

End Sub
```

The to use the procedure, call it like so:

```
Sub SomeProc()

fExportPDF ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:B3"), "C:\Some Location\example.pdf"

End Sub
```

Comment: same error... if you see all three codes in my question are correct. but none works.... I dont know why it is giving me error. Is there a problem with my computer? other pdf files are opening properly.

Comment: Is the PDF Add-In installed? See the note from Microsoft: `An error will occur if the PDF add-in is not currently installed.` I tested the above code and worked fine on my machine?

Comment: yes... that was the reason. I installed the addin and it worked. Now that is dangerous... if the addin is not installed on user's machine then the code will terminate with an error. How to handle this situation?. Is there a way to detect if the addid is installed OR from an error event, how can we give a link to download the addin in an alertbox? The link is http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=9943. Thanks

Comment: Should really be in a new question but you need to check and see if the file `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE12\EXP_ODF.DLL` exists or not.

Comment: Ok Thanks. The msdn document also says about xps format. Do you think xps would work without pdf addin or is there a xps addin too? there is nothing mentioned anything there.

Comment: XPS is also an addin which can be checked at `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE12\EXP_XPS.DLL

Comment: Thank you. I hope the path is same for all excel versions from 97 - 2013